# iOS / HTTP Server communication, device to device

Tags: swift, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, bonjour, zeroconf

In the past few days, I've been reading a lot of articles and Stackoverflow questions.

We are looking to transfer data between a Windows IOT PC and an iPad. We would like a HTTP Server, without using a WIFI access point from the IOT PC or being on the same network.

It seems like Bluetooth Low Energy (BTLE) would be the way to go, along with Bonjour maybe?

Actually, we are using a medical device SDK that requires Bonjour Discovery in our iOS app's `Info.plist` and the service is named `_Manufacturer_https._tcp`, so it seems pretty much possible.

Would you guys have guidelines? Or a step-by-step tutorial?

Comment: You want to send http packets via BLE?

Comment: Hi @MichaelKotzjan, I suppose! I want to be able to query a HTTP server exposed on the PC, without connecting to the same local network, from an iPad.

Bluetooth seems the way to go, or at least, for discovery, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You can send whatever you want using Bluetooth :) You could definitely assemble a HTTP request and send it as a string via Bluetooth. Or you could send your data 'raw' and restructure them on receiving. I don't think there is a step-by-step tutorial for that exact use case. There is [this part](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices) of Apple's documentation describing how to do data transfer between your iOS and a BLE device